# What is the word used in Mexico to mean "slang"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, méxico, solicitud-de-término

I've tried "argot" and "jerga" and no one seems to understand me. "Modismo" also doesn't count because that seems to be used more for sayings like "An apple a day..."

For example:

> - Oye, cuando yo escucho mis grabaciones yo puedo entender cada palabra, pero hay algunas personas, incluido tú, a quien casi nunca entiendo.
> - A lo mejor es porque estás hablando _________.

Comment: _¿Coloquialismo?_

Comment: I'll try that. Also, is there another word that might also have a vulgar connotation but not necessarily a curse word per say?

Comment: I wouldn't know, since I speak Spanish from Spain. Note by the way that [_jerga_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=GQu6RhY4wx0AmZHg1w6) in Mexico has the meaning of _ Trapo de cocina o de limpieza en general_!! Finally, to get a clearer question, could you provide a couple of examples on where you would use the word?

Comment: Oye, cuando yo escucho mis grabaciones yo puedo entender cada palabra, pero hay algunas personas, incluyo tu, quien entiendo casi nunca. A lo mejor es porque estas hablando _________. A propósito, bas se deletrea con v...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spanish, being such a vocabulary and synonym rich language, you'll find at least three or four different terms that adequately convey the broad  meaning of almost concept that you wish to articulate, however most of the time, there are subtle nuances and implied meanings (connotations) when using different words for the same concept.. Add regionalisms to the mix, and using the "right" word becomes a fun task to say the least.

This is a good example: since **Jerga** certainly conveys the meaning of *slang* it is nonetheless a very neutral, "internationalized - standard" word that most people with at least a high-school level vocabulary will understand both in Spain, and Hispanic America. It does, however sound a little "off" in everyday speech.

A more accurate term in common use for 'slang' in México is **Caló** (There even used to be a rap band named exactly that! [Caló: El Cubo](https://youtu.be/TJzl9anrZOs) even though the vocalist **can** rap, the rest of the act is embarrassingly kitsch.)

**Coloquial** is also a good, standard term for 'slang'. However,**Jerga** , **Caló**, and **Coloquial** are hardly ever used outside formal linguistic studies.

Most Mexican Spanish speakers will qualify speech as "corriente" (cheap) as in "su forma de hablar es muy corriente / it is a very cheap way of talking". Mexico City favors the more insular *Guarro* but that has a heavy rudeness connotation. Lately, "*naco*" has also been used to describe slang, though that has a connotation of ignorance and unsophistication, (usaste una frase muy naca / you used a very kitsch phrase).

Its probably worth mentioning that at least in Mexico, the very word "Slang" is well understood with the same meaning as in English as a kind of "loan word". That may not hold true in Central America or Spain, though.

In conclusion, be safe and use "Coloquial", or even "Slang". Or have some fun and try your luck with *Naco*, its probably not any worse than whatever actual slang you may be  pointing out =)

Comment: I upvoted this answer, which I thought was excellent and very helpful *except* I want to warn readers that in my opinion, people could take offense with *naco*.  hlecuanda, I'm not sure if you took into account that when a foreigner says a word like *naco* it might come across differently than when someone who was obviously born and raised in Mexico says it. // I think you could strengthen your answer by giving some guidance about how to pronounce *slang* in Spanish.  My guess is "eslang" with the S sounding like a Z -- is that right?  Similar to *snob* = *esnob*?

Comment: You have a good point. And yes *eslang* or *slang* will be equally understood just about anywhere. About warning on the use of lang with people you don't know: I feel *common sense is the best guide* when choosing when to use any language's **100 shades of rude**, where context, and non-verbal cues make all the difference! The same slang *Guey* if said in jest and good spirits will have the same meaning as  *dude* whereas if uttered with a frown or a  menacing demeanor, will convey something like *nitwit* or *idiot*. I'd keep my slang when in trough a tough neighborhood, for example.

Comment: OTOH, Culturally, We, Mexicans, are immensely welcoming of foreigners and will go out of our way to understand and befriend them, and acts of kindness that may be considered extraordinary elsewhere, are thought of as "the least we can do" for our guests.. As long as you are ok with  a laugh or two at your expense, you will find people from all walks of life that don't speak a word of english trying their best to understand what have to say. Again, use common sense (YMMV in some communities). Check out Connan O'brien's "Made in Mexico" episodes and you'll see what I mean. https://goo.gl/attYqH

Comment: I'll take a look at the videos you recommended.  I couldn't agree more about your cultural comment.  I thought of a possible analogy for *naco* -- "nigger/nigga", where context can flip the meaning and the emotional reaction 180 degrees.  Is that too strong a statement?

Comment: i'm gonna say yes, its a little out of proportion. *Naco* is more like *kitsch* or the british *chav*, while demeaning and pointing out lack of sophistication or finesse in someone; it has **nowhere near** the racial slur connotations that *Nigga/Nigger* has in english. That may be the case because most discrimination in mexico is income-based and we've been a diverse population since the XVI Century. (Again YMMV in some indigenous communities).  A better analogy would be perhaps *Dork* which is very different coming from a brother or sister rather than an angry Yankees fan upset at the game.

Comment: I agree that "nigger" is very strong and negative.  But "nigga" has taken on a different meaning and connotation.  I was wondering if "naco" also varies in innuendo depending on who says it and in what context.  Here's another analogy: in some contexts, "Jew" is used in a racist way.  In others, it's used as a neutral, factual description.  In yet others, it's used with pride. // I really don't think *naca* means *kitsch*.  I think it means *country bumpkin*.with as dismissive a tone as *trailer park trash*.

Comment: I'm not sure if _naco_ is even on the same category as the aforementioned _n_-words, because being considered _naco_ is something *anyone* could be considered as regardless of background or any arbitrary measure, and also *anyone* can grow out of by bettering themselves educating and refining  language, manners and taste. OTOH, **racial epithets** such as *nigger* or its   derivatives (a racist epithet by any other name) are just an expression of hate towards a class of people defined  by some arbitrary measure that is inherent to that group, such as ethnicity, religion or cultural heritage.

Answer (score 0):

**Jerga** is the word I always heard and used while living in Mexico.

If people don't understand you, maybe your pronunciation is off a bit? [Forvo might be of help in that case.](https://forvo.com/word/jerga/)

Comment: Very much so, and forvo is a great help.

Comment: You may have also experienced that most mexicans -generally- will go out of their way to try and make sense of even the most contrived pronunciation, by asking if you meant one thing or the other. Its hard to not be understood by being a little "off" in pronunciation unless you're speaking actual greek . Jerga is good, but too formal in everyday non-academic speech, though.

Comment: I agree.  Also, *jerga* is an extremely common word for a ubiquitous household object, and people will have a hard time not thinking of that other meaning if they hear the word.  (It's the damp cloth or rag used to clean the floor -- similar to what's used in the US, the sponge mop.  What I mean is, the mechanics are slightly different, but the purpose is the same as *mopping the floor* ("pasar jerga").